# Loop through changing xpath values w/ Selenium

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm working on scraping a site that has a dropdown menu of hundreds of schools. I am trying to go through and grab tables for only schools from a certain district in the state. So far I have isolated the values for only those schools, but I've bee unable to replace the xpath values from what is stored in my dataframe/list.

Here is my code:

```
ousd_list = ousd['name'].to_list()
for i in range(0,129): 
    n = 0
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(('"//option[@value="',ousd_list[n],']"'))
    driver.find_elements_by_name("submit1").click()
    table = driver.find_elements_by_id("ContentPlaceHolder1_grdDisc")
    tdf = pd.read_html(table)
    tdf.to_csv(index=False)
    n += 1
    driver.get('https://dq.cde.ca.gov/dataquest/Expulsion/ExpSearchName.asp?TheYear=2018-19&cTopic=Expulsion&cLevel=School&cName=&cCounty=&cTimeFrame=S')
```

I suspect the issue is on the find_element_by_xpath line, but I'm not sure how else I would go about resolving this issue. Any advice?

Comment: Why use i and n? Also n resets to 0.

Comment: So are you saying I should use a while loop instead? Or just different variables?

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is not in the scraping part but your code logic, since you put `n=0` in the beginning of your loop, it resets to 0 and every loop will just find your `ousd_list[0]`.

Try,

```
ousd_list = ousd['name'].to_list()
for ousd_name in ousd_list : 
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//option[@value="{ousd_name}"]')
    driver.find_elements_by_name("submit1").click()
    table = driver.find_elements_by_id("ContentPlaceHolder1_grdDisc")
    tdf = pd.read_html(table)
    tdf.to_csv(index=False)
    driver.get('https://dq.cde.ca.gov/dataquest/Expulsion/ExpSearchName.asp?TheYear=2018-19&cTopic=Expulsion&cLevel=School&cName=&cCounty=&cTimeFrame=S')
```

Comment: This does what you said it would but it doesn't fix the problem. I'm getting the following error message: 

InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: 'value' must be a string

which references this line: driver.find_element_by_xpath(('"//option[@value="',ousd_name,']"'))

Comment: `but it doesn't fix the problem` This snippet fixed the problem you specified in this thread, your new problem is that the xpath is improperly formatted, which is not in this scope of your question. Therefore, it DOES fix your ASKED problem, since you have a new problem, you should be opening a new thread for that different question. However, for the sake of saving time, I replaced your string with f-string and it should work now.